# Java 8 Stream filter map in map -- Map<String,Map<String,Employee>>

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

How to filter a `Map<String,Map<String,Employee>>` using Java 8 Filter?

I have to filter only when any of employee in the list having a field value Gender = "M".

Input:

> `Map<String,Map<String,Employee>>`

Output:

> `Map<String,Map<String,Employee>>`

Filter criteria:

> `Employee.genter = "M"`

Also i have to return empty map if the filtered result is empty.

I tried the below, but it is not working as expected. It is returning the only if all the Employees are with gender "M".

```
tempCollection.entrySet().stream()
                        .filter(i -> i.getValue().entrySet().stream().allMatch(e-> "M".equals(e.getValue().getGender())))
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: Return all the employees whose gender is M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply iterate on the key-value pairs and filter as:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Employee>> output = new HashMap<>();
tempCollection.forEach((k, v) -> {
    if (v.values().stream().anyMatch(i -> "M".equals(i.getGender()))) {
        output.put(k, v.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(i -> "M".equals(i.getValue().getGender()))
                .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)));
    }
});
```

Comment: anyMatch returns all the result even there is a single match, I want the key value to be removed if there is no match,

Comment: If none of the employee is with the Gender "M", it still returns Map<String,emptyMap()>

Comment: @user1578872 *i have to return empty map if the filtered result is empty.*.. that's what you meant, right?

Comment: It should be completeEmpty map in this case. Like, return emptyMap(), not Map<String,emptyMap()>

Comment: @user1578872 so do you mean if any of the internal `Map` doesn't have any employee with gender equal to `M` return the outer `Map` as *empty*??

Comment: If any of the internal Map doesn't have any employee with gender equal to M, The corresponding key should be removed.

Comment: @user1578872 Updated, i guess this should be it.

Comment: I think `put` would be more ideal rather than `putIfAbsent` as the `key` will always be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like what you're after is given a `Entry<String,Map<String,Employee>>` if there's any employee who has a gender of "M" then filter the inner `Map<String,Employee>` to contain only entries with a gender "M".

in which case you can `filter` along with `anyMatch` for the first criterion. Further, at the collecting phase, you can then apply the filtering on the inner map:

```
tempCollection.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(i -> i.getValue().values().stream().anyMatch(e -> "M".equals(e.getGender())))
            .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    v -> v.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                            .filter(i -> "M".equals(i.getValue().getGender()))
                            .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue))));
```

Comment: anyMatch returns all the values in the map even there is only one employee with Gender M.

Comment: @user1578872 right, thanks to the accepted answer, I can now understand your requirement. the description wasn't very clear IMO. anyway edited to accommodate.

Answer (score 1):

The function `allMatch` only matches if every element in the stream matches the predicate; you can use `anyMatch` to match if any element matches the predicate:

```
tempCollection.entrySet().stream()
                        .filter(i -> i.getValue().entrySet().stream().anyMatch(e-> "M".equals(e.getValue().getGender())))
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do it like so,

```
Map<String, Map<String, Employee>> maleEmpMap = tempCollection.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(),
        e.getValue().entrySet().stream().filter(emp -> "M".equals(emp.getValue().getGender()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue))))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Take each map entry from the outer map and create a new map entry using the same key and the newly constructed nested map with the same key and which has only male employees as it's value. Finally collect all those matching entries into a new outer map. This will gracefully handle the empty scenario which you mentioned in the problem statement above.

Answer (score 0):

Other way would be like this:

```
map.values()
     .removeIf(entry->entry.values().stream().anyMatch(e -> !"M".equals(e.getGender())));

map.entrySet()
    .removeIf(entry->entry.getValue().size() == 0);
```